# Cannot access data from mysql table using object oriented style of php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie at PHP. I'm simply trying to access my database and here is the code. I'm using the object oriented style for accessing the database. 
It says "Trying to get property of non-object on line 25".
What am I missing?

```
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
//$username = "";
//$password = "";
$database = "MyPetProject";

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $database);

if ($conn-> connect_error)
{
die ("Connection failed : " . $conn->connect_error);  
}
else
{
echo "Connection Successfull";
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM User";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row["Sr.no"] . " " . $row["Name"] . " " . $row["Online"];
    }

}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}



echo ("hello world");


$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: What's on line 25? Check your database connection first, it looks fishy. [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: I am getting "Connection Successful" message. I guess database connection is fine. This is on line 25: if($result->num_rows > 0)

Comment: *hmm*, `$result` is not an object then. On success, `SELECT` returns a `mysqli_result` object, and on failure it returns false. So your query has failed to execute, debug that. `mysqli::$error` would have helped you in this case, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: You were right in the first place. It was a database connection issue. Answered below!

Comment: no error reporting established with your script. No try catch block, and you are just guessing and plodding forward with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

I had commented $username and $password.

These are mandatory parameters for mysqli. The rest of the code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following:
 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc($result))
And it should work

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. It says "Trying to get property of non-object" for the line " if($result->num_rows > 0) "

Comment: @Satty, `while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){...` is correct,[http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples). The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You should need a username and password for accessing mysql databases .

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

which is the second and third parameters respectively.

> You could find all related documentation in this link.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php